# How to configure RubyMine, so I can go to the component declaration?

Tags: ember.js, rubymine

While working with emberjs there are two ways to invoke a component in a template: classic invocation syntax

```
{{my-component}}
```

and the angle bracket invocation syntax

```
<MyConmonent />
```

You can go to the component declaration by simply pressing `command + left click`.
But this doesn't work for the angle bracket syntax

Is there a way to configure the RubyMine or install some plugin to get it working?

BTW, using the `EmberJs` plugin written by Tobias Bieniek doesn't resolve this issue

Comment: It works perfectly in WebStorm. Have you updated the plugin to the latest version?

Comment: @AndreyStukalin yes, I have the latest version of it